# Phoenix / Elixir: When are handle_in / handle_out called?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am confused about when `handle_in/3` and `handle_out/3` are called. Handle in sounds like it would "handle any incoming events broadcasted by other clients", but given I have this code:

web/static/js/app.js

`channel.push("blah", {});`

web/channels/call_channel.ex

```
  intercept ["blah"]

  def handle_in("blah", params, socket) do
    Logger.info "handle_in blah"
    broadcast! socket, "message", params
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_out("blah", payload, socket) do
    Logger.info "handle_out blah"
    push socket, "blah", payload
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

and I refresh my page, I see `handle_in blah` printed out in the log, but not `handle_out blah`:

```
[info] GET /
[debug] Processing by VideoChat.CallController.index/2
  Parameters: %{}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 166µs
[info] JOIN user_pool to VideoChat.CallChannel
  Transport:  Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket
  Parameters: %{"device_id" => "c6fbf94u3d"}
[info] Replied user_pool :ok
[info] handle_in blah
```

Does that mean `handle_in` is called when "any events are sent from within" and `handle_out` is called when "any evens are received from outside"?

Comment: I believe you need to `intercept` `"blah"`. See https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#intercept/1.

Comment: hey. just tried it and it didn't work

Comment: you are intercepting "blah" but broadcasting "message"

Comment: oooo good call. is my theory on handle_in / out correct?

Comment: looks like it should work. Although it is kind of pointless in the code you wrote. If you have it in handle_in why not do the work of interception right there and boradcast/push inline? Interception is intended for cases where work of interception and data producer are too far from each other. In the case you sohwed they are not, although if this a contrived example then it might explain things :-)